# Ember.js ember-data and cross-domain ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

folks! Any examples of using ember-data to store data getted from remote server with cross-domain ajax request? Now I have this, but...

```
TravelClient.Tour = Ember.Object.extend({
});

TravelClient.Tour.reopenClass({
  allTours: [],
  find: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://someIP:somePORT/tours.json',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      context: this,
      success: function(data){
        data.forEach(function(tour){
          this.allTours.addObject(TravelClient.Tour.create(tour))
        }, this)
      }
    })
    return this.allTours;
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Now i'm doing it in this way:

```
TravelClient.Tour.reopenClass({
  allTours: [],
  find: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://someIP:somePORT/tours.json',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      context: this,
      success: function(response){
        response.data.forEach(function(tour){
          this.allTours.addObject(TravelClient.Tour.create(tour))
        }, this)
      }
    })
    return this.allTours;
  }
});
```

But get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
```

**SNAPSHOT:**

with this:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url:"http://192.168.1.39:3000/tours.json",
  success:function(response){
    return response.data;
  }
});
```

I get this:

```
Object
abort: function (e){var t=e||S;return r&&r.abort(t),N(0,t),this}
always: function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
complete: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){y.each(t,function(t,n){var i=y.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
done: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){y.each(t,function(t,n){var i=y.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
error: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){y.each(t,function(t,n){var i=y.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
fail: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){y.each(t,function(t,n){var i=y.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return E===2?s:null}
getResponseHeader: function (e){var t;if(E===2){if(!o){o={};while(t=wn.exec(s))o[t[1].toLowerCase()]=t[2]}t=o[e.toLowerCase()]}return t==null?null:t}
overrideMimeType: function (e){return E||(c.mimeType=e),this}
pipe: function (){var e=arguments;return y.Deferred(function(n){y.each(t,function(t,s){var o=s[0],u=y.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[s[1]](function(){var e=u&&u.apply(this,arguments);e&&y.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[o+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,u?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){y.each(t,function(t,n){var i=y.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
promise: function (e){return e!=null?y.extend(e,r):r}
readyState: 4
setRequestHeader: function (e,t){var n=e.toLowerCase();return E||(e=b[n]=b[n]||e,g[e]=t),this}
state: function (){return n}
status: 200
statusCode: function (e){var t;if(e)if(E<2)for(t in e)m[t]=[m[t],e[t]];else x.always(e[x.status]);return this}
statusText: "success"
success: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){y.each(t,function(t,n){var i=y.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
then: function (){var e=arguments;return y.Deferred(function(n){y.each(t,function(t,s){var o=s[0],u=y.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[s[1]](function(){var e=u&&u.apply(this,arguments);e&&y.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[o+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,u?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a about how the server should return data to the client than about ember-data, what you need to do is, wrap the response to the ajax call in a callback whose value is sent as a parameter to the server. Once you do that, it's business as usual for ember-data i.e quite transparent to it

Here's an example using ruby on rails

On the client side

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
       // loop through your objects
       response.accounts.forEach(function(account){
          console.info(account.id)
       })
    }
});
```

On the server side you should do something similar to

```
params[:callback] + '("' + response + '");';
```

Yielding for example a response similar to:

```
callbackValue00923411(
    {
        "accounts":
        [
            {
                "id": 123,
                "name": "Personal",
            },
            {
                "id": 234,
                "name": "Corporate",
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Then in your success function you access the list of accounts, as I stated above, this way

```
success: function(response) {
   // loop through your objects
   response.accounts.forEach(function(account){
      console.info(account.id)
   })
}
```

Here's an [example](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) on how to use/handle jsonp ajax request

If you have access to the server, you may consider configuring it to use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) instead and avoid using jsonp

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your response.

Comment: check out snapshot in answer.

Comment: @Nikita, i meant server response to 'http://someIP:somePORT/tours.json', that you can get using chrome console for example in Network tab. Anyways i think your problem is related to the way you're accessing your response data. I updated my reply. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I just wanted to add that you should escape ```params[:callback]``` and not use it directly, obviously this is just an example but that could be a major XXS vulnerability.